# PySpark PCA: get number of components from model object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have a fit a PCA model in PySpark and I need to get the number of components from the model object.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
pca = PCA(k=5, inputCol='features', outputCol='components')
pca_model = pca.fit(data)
```

I tried using `pca_model.k` and `pca_model.getParam('k')` but none of them gives me the number of components.

```
>>> pca_model.k
Param(parent='PCA_4e66a98132a4fe4ad86c', name='k', doc='the number of principal components (> 0)')
>>> pca_model.getParam('k')
Param(parent='PCA_4e66a98132a4fe4ad86c', name='k', doc='the number of principal components (> 0)')
```

How do I get the number of components from PySpark's `PCAModel` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use its Java model:

```
pca_model._java_obj.getK()
```

or `getOrDefault` method:

```
pca_model.getOrDefault("k")
```